# Stop proliferation of [cells]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I was recently considering going through the MATLAB tag and retagging questions labeled [cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cell) as the more MATLAB-specific [cell-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cell-array), when I realized we've got both [cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cell) (3,281 posts) and [cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cells) (753 posts) as tags. They both predominantly cover Excel and tables (and the aforementioned MATLAB), and I already combined their similar tag wikis into a more general tag wiki for [cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cell).

Can we get our chimera on and [merge these cells](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cell/synonyms)?

**EDIT:** Just for clarity, I'm only suggesting merging [cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cells) into [cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cell). Retagging of MATLAB questions with [cell-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cell-array) is another issue entirely.

Comment: Is this tag really necessary? As far I'm aware, none of us is interested in the biology of the question, but it's development of software aspects, and cell, isn't a software development related term, not even a product name. I think we are better off without it. So, poison all the cells!

Comment: @Braiam But then how would any ask about their [cell] [phone]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cell%20phone

Comment: @Kara oh god no...

Comment: @Braiam: Agreed with Braiam, I am not quite sure `cell` really helps finding questions. Do we really need this tag? If not, a burnination would be more appropriate.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Aside from MATLAB (which should use `cell-array` instead), the next highest related tags are `excel`, `ios`, and `uitableview`. I can't comment on how useful it may be for those tags. If it's not that useful, maybe a complete nuking is in order.

Comment: @MatthieuM. actually, it doesn't help people *answering* questions. Those are the main consumers of tags, and you can't know everything there's to know about cells on a programming context (too varied).

Comment: @Braiam: Sometimes tags are used in compound ways though, so maybe someone would filter on excel + cell, or ios + cell? Bit far-fetched... but that's the point of a proper burnination request: investing whether it's worth keeping or not :)

Comment: @MatthieuM. I've heard that in the past... I find it extremely unlikely, as most answerers just create a new tag for the topic they are interested about if the existing tags are too crowded (think lang vs lib) or the topic is new.